# How to use entitymanager with Micronaut?

Tags: java, entitymanager, micronaut

I'm new in Micronaut framework and I'm trying to use entitymanager to create my repository.
I created my repository like this

```
public interface EmployeeRepository {
    Employee save(@NotNull Employee employee);
    Employee update(@NotNull Employee employee);
    List<Employee> findAll();
    Optional<Employee> findById(@NotNull Long id);
}
```

and I used this class to implement the interface and to inject entitymanager

```
@Singleton
public class EmployeeRepositoryImpl implements EmployeeRepository{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EmployeeRepositoryImpl(@CurrentSession EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Employee save(@NotNull Employee employee) {
        entityManager.persist(employee);
        return employee;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Employee update(@NotNull Employee employee) {
        return entityManager.merge(employee);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        String qlString = "SELECT * FROM Employee";
        TypedQuery<Employee> query = entityManager.createQuery(qlString, Employee.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Optional<Employee> findById(@NotNull Long id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(entityManager.find(Employee.class, id));
    }
}
```

The problem is that I have always this error :

```
Message: No bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManager] exists. Ensure the class is declared a bean and if you are using Java or Kotlin make sure you have enabled annotation processing.
Path Taken: new $EmployeeControllerDefinition$Intercepted([EmployeeRepositoryImpl employeeRepository],BeanContext beanContext,Interceptor[] interceptors) --> new $EmployeeRepositoryImplDefinition$Intercepted([EntityManager entityManager],BeanContext beanContext,Interceptor[] interceptors)
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [entityManager] of class: com.milamed.dao.$EmployeeRepositoryImplDefinition$Intercepted
```

PS: I have enabled the annotation processing

Comment: Are you using `io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-jpa`?

Comment: This happened when the `jpa.default.packages-to-scan` property wasn't pointing to the entities objects (was pointing to my DAO package instead). Fixing that creating the `EntityManager`. The error message around this could be improved IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't provided enough about your project to know for sure what is missing but I have created a working example for you at https://github.com/jeffbrown/mohamedmiledijpa.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mohamedmiledijpa/blob/master/src/main/java/mohamedmiledijpa/Employee.java

```
package mohamedmiledijpa;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mohamedmiledijpa/blob/master/src/main/java/mohamedmiledijpa/EmployeeRepository.java

```
package mohamedmiledijpa;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface EmployeeRepository {
    Employee save(@NotNull Employee employee);
    Employee update(@NotNull Employee employee);
    List<Employee> findAll();
    Optional<Employee> findById(@NotNull Long id);
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mohamedmiledijpa/blob/master/src/main/java/mohamedmiledijpa/EmployeeRepositoryImpl.java

```
package mohamedmiledijpa;

import io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.scope.CurrentSession;
import io.micronaut.spring.tx.annotation.Transactional;

import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Singleton
public class EmployeeRepositoryImpl implements EmployeeRepository{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EmployeeRepositoryImpl(@CurrentSession EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Employee save(@NotNull Employee employee) {
        entityManager.persist(employee);
        return employee;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Employee update(@NotNull Employee employee) {
        return entityManager.merge(employee);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        String qlString = "SELECT e FROM Employee e";
        TypedQuery<Employee> query = entityManager.createQuery(qlString, Employee.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Optional<Employee> findById(@NotNull Long id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(entityManager.find(Employee.class, id));
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mohamedmiledijpa/blob/master/src/main/java/mohamedmiledijpa/EmployeeController.java

```
package mohamedmiledijpa;

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Body;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;

import java.util.List;

@Controller("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeController(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    @Get("/")
    public List<Employee> list() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Post("/")
    public Employee create(@Body Employee employee) {
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mohamedmiledijpa/blob/f6500d3fb24190ed59ca64dcc28a02f8069fedfd/build.gradle#L29

```
compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-jpa"
```

That all appears to work:

```
~ $ curl http://localhost:8080/employee
[]
~ $ 
~ $ curl -d '{"name":"Jake"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  http://localhost:8080/employee
{"id":1,"name":"Jake"}
~ $ 
~ $ curl -d '{"name":"Zack"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST  http://localhost:8080/employee
{"id":2,"name":"Zack"}
~ $ 
~ $ curl http://localhost:8080/employee
[{"id":1,"name":"Jake"},{"id":2,"name":"Zack"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it still not working with the same error. Maybe the problem is in my configuration, this is my application.yml file `micronaut:
  application:
    name: micronaut
jpa:
  default:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update


dataSource:
  dbCreate: create-update
  pooled: true
  jmxExport: true
  driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  username: root
  password:
  dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/micronaut`

Comment: @MohamedMiledi There are any number of things that might be wrong.  If you can share a project which demonstrates the error, it could be diagnosed.  You asked "How to use entitymanager with Micronaut?" and the project linked above shows you one way to do it.

Comment: What package is your `Application` class in and what package(s) are your `@Entity` classes in?

Comment: ok, this is the link of the github repo `https://github.com/milamed/micronaut.git`

Comment: The config at https://github.com/milamed/micronaut/blob/59bb601d02f32586c2453a358569ebc790512f1b/src/main/resources/application.yml#L12-L20 has a few things wrong with it.  It has hard to say what your intent there was but you are missing a `default` config.  Run `mn create-app --features hibernate-jpa com.milamed.micronaut` and compare the generated `src/main/resources/application.yml` to yours.

Comment: The config in the app I linked above (https://github.com/jeffbrown/mohamedmiledijpa/blob/f6500d3fb24190ed59ca64dcc28a02f8069fedfd/src/main/resources/application.yml) will show you the same thing.

Comment: I created a relevant pull request at https://github.com/milamed/micronaut/pull/1.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue, and I found the solution:

If you're using @PersistenceContext for injecting the EntityManger, you need to include this dependency:

{Using Gradle}

```
compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-jdbc-hikari"
```

or
{Using Maven}

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
  <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

as this is the way that micronaut locates the DataSources defined in your application.yml.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
I solved it adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
  <artifactId>micronaut-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, if you already have this dependency I recomend you to check if you have the same dependecies this man has (his project is done in gradle but you can search the dependency in maven repository too):

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mohamedmiledijpa.