# Micronaut, JPA , EntityManager : without datasource from application.yml gives error 'No transaction manager configured'

Tags: jpa, entitymanager, spring-transactions, micronaut

I am trying to use JPA Transaction management with batch insertion using Micronaut + Postgresql.

*| Micronaut Version: 1.1.3
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_212*

I have configured Micronaut project to use 'micronaut-hibernate-jpa' in build.gradle.

```
compile "io.micronaut.configuration:micronaut-hibernate-jpa"
```

high level approach is like this and is working fine when datasource is defined in application.yml.

my interface

```
interface myrepository
{
  savebatch (@NotNull List<ConsumerRecord<String, MyBusinessClass>> buffer
}
```

my interface implementation

```
@Slf4j
@Singleton
@EnableTransactionManagement
class myrepositoryimpl implements myrepository
{
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager

  myrepositoryimpl(@CurrentSession EntityManager entityManager){
   this.entityManager = entityManager
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional    
  public savebatch (...)
  {
      ..some business logic
       entity.persist(...)
    ....
      entity.flush()
      entity.clear()
   }
}
```

Above code is running fine if I use datasource from application.yml.

**My requirement is**: my application requires to create datasources at run-time . So I removed dagtasource & other details from application.yml and creating at runtime.

for dynamic approach. I am initializing EntityManger in constructor with following code snippet, 
but its throwing runtime error as '**No transaction manager configured**'

```
HibernatePersistenceProvider hibernatePersistenceProvider = new HibernatePersistenceProvider();

Map <String,Object> properties = new HashMap<String,Object>();

properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.JPA_JDBC_DRIVER, 'org.postgresql.Driver')
properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.JPA_JDBC_URL, 'jdbc:postgresql://...')
properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.DIALECT, PostgreSQL10Dialect.class)
properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.JPA_JDBC_USER, '...')
properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.JPA_JDBC_PASSWORD, '...')

properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings.SHOW_SQL, false)

EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = hibernatePersistenceProvider
        .createContainerEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitInfo, properties);

def entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()

log.info "Setting entity manager factory "
JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

txManager.setEntityManagerFactory((EntityManagerFactory)entityManagerFactory);
DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
        .driverClassName('org.postgresql.Driver')
        .url('jdbc:postgresql://...')
        .password('...')
        .username('...')
        .build()

if (dataSource!= null){
    log.info "Valid datasource created"
    txManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
}

context.registerSingleton(entityManager)

return entityManager
```

}

followed few links and google.

https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-data-access-jpa-hibernate/guide/index.html

https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/#graalJPA

[How to use entitymanager with Micronaut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000143/how-to-use-entitymanager-with-micronaut)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are creating the entity manager manually, that is unnecessary as Micronaut already includes the ability to automatically setup an entity manager for you. See https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-sql/latest/guide/#hibernate

However if you must do that then when registering a singleton you have to register it with a named qualifier of "default" since that is what Micronaut expects the default data source to be called and you also have to register the datasource itself as a bean.

```
context.registerSingleton(dataSource, Qualifiers.byName("default"));
context.registerSingleton(entityManager, Qualifiers.byName("default"));
```

However like I said this is not a supported or recommended approach to configuring the entity manager factory

Comment: Thank you Graeme, 
`@PersistentContext
EntityManager` is binding automatically to the datasource defined in application.yml. However, my requirement is to create database connections at run time. Since my business req is to create 'Tenants' dynamically, a Database will be created and I want datasource at that time.

flow would be: read tenant info at application boot, create data sources through progrm, and connect to the data.
Tenant's info will be stored in a separate db, with diff credentials, so I am avoiding application.yml .

Comment: @Nitin Did you find a way? Got the same issue.